# Unable to resolve ATOM version on windows powershell

Tags: powershell, atom-editor, ethereum

I am installing **ethereum** test environment on my PC.

I have already installed : **geth**, **ganache**, **node.js** , **atom**

Now when i try to check version of my respected tools in powershell (`atom -v`)then i am getting everything correctly except the atom version is not showing up.

**Error**:

> 'atom' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.Check the spelling of the name or if a path was
>   included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Your question can be improved by removing the image and replacing it with the text content of the image.  See https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @Amy, thank you :) I removed the screenshot and wrote the error msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `PATH` environment variable to include the folder where Atom is installed in, which is normally: `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom`